# Rollup issue: resolve failed, mootools already loaded, must be run with ava?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

I'm having an error that makes absolutely no sense. I haven't run `rollup -c` in about an month and running it now is causing all sorts of mayhem.

#### 1) `mootools` already loaded

Why on earth is `mootools already loaded` in the log of this error? What is using `mootools`?

#### 2) How is rolllup triggering ava?

If you scroll all the way at the bottom, I keen getting this random issue complaining that the bin itself needs to be run with `ava`.

```
Test files must be run with the AVA CLI: `ava node_modules/.bin/rollup`
```

#### 3) Apparently missing `dependencies`.

The script is complaining about `babel-runtime`, `n`, `foreman` which is odd because I installed all of these. Just to make sure.

#### 4) I've changed the `entry`

I've cleared the `entry` file to not contain any dependencies itself and the same errors still happen.

Here's my config:

```
module.exports = {
  external: [],
  entry: './src/appProxypass/index.js',
  dest: './packages/proxypass-app/index.js',
  format: 'cjs',
  plugins: [
    require('rollup-plugin-commonjs')({
    }),
    require('rollup-plugin-babel')({
      babelrc: false,
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      // externalHelpers: true,
      'presets': [
        'es2015-rollup',
        'stage-2'
      ],
      'plugins': [
        'transform-runtime',
        'transform-async-to-generator',
        'syntax-async-functions',
        'transform-flow-strip-types',
        'transform-class-properties'
      ],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    require('rollup-plugin-cleanup')()
  ]
}
```

Here's my errors:

```
> rollup -c

resolve failed:  { Error: Cannot find module 'n'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.requireRelative.resolve (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/node_modules/require-relative/index.js:30:17)
    at resolve (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:25:26)
    at findAndRemove (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:67:11)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:111:13
    at Array.map (native)
    at loadPreset (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:103:29)
    at module.exports (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/index.js:97:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:302:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:270:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:259:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:244:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:374:12) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } n
mootools already loaded
resolve failed:  { Error: Cannot find module 'foreman'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.requireRelative.resolve (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/node_modules/require-relative/index.js:30:17)
    at resolve (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:25:26)
    at findAndRemove (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:67:11)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:111:13
    at Array.map (native)
    at loadPreset (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:103:29)
    at module.exports (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/index.js:97:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:302:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:270:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:259:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:244:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:374:12) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } foreman
resolve failed:  { Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.requireRelative.resolve (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/node_modules/require-relative/index.js:30:17)
    at resolve (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:25:26)
    at findAndRemove (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:67:11)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:111:13
    at Array.map (native)
    at loadPreset (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:103:29)
    at module.exports (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/index.js:97:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:302:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:270:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:259:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:244:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:374:12) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } babel-runtime

Test files must be run with the AVA CLI:

    $ ava node_modules/.bin/rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has something to do with `rollup-plugin-babel`. I removed it, and I'm using rollup on the `lib` version (built) rather then the `src`.

```
module.exports = {
  external: [],
  entry: './lib/appProxypass/index.js',
  dest: './packages/proxypass-app/index.js',
  format: 'cjs',
  plugins: [
    require('rollup-plugin-commonjs')(),
    require('rollup-plugin-cleanup')()
  ]
}
```