# Unexpected token at "async" call with rollup

Tags: javascript, async-await, rollupjs

I have async support with babel working in my project and I've copied and pasted my settings over. I rollup processing past the `async` declaration. Why can't rollup process async / await? How can I build my code sucessfully?

> Error parsing /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/src/appProxypass/index.js: Unexpected token (43:44) in /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/PAS/PAS-api/src/appProxypass/index.js

```
module.exports = {
  exports: 'named',
  external: [],
  entry: './src/appProxypass/index.js',
  dest: './packages/proxypass-app/index.js',
  format: 'cjs',
  plugins: [
    require('rollup-plugin-commonjs')(),
    require('rollup-plugin-babel')({
      "babelrc": false,
      "exclude": 'packages/proxypass-app/node_modules/**',
      "include": 'packages/proxypass-app/**',
      "runtimeHelpers": true,
      "externalHelpers": true,
      "plugins": [
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        "syntax-async-functions",
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-class-properties",
        [
          "transform-strict-mode",
          {
            "strict": false
          }
        ]
      ],
      "presets": [
        "es2015-rollup",
        "stage-2"
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you create a repo and/or link to the file that it's failing on?

Comment: @RichHarris https://github.com/reggi/example-rollup-failure-async

Comment: In your example, the file in question isn't being transpiled by Babel (because you've specified `include`), so the code Rollup sees still has the `async` function (which isn't valid ES2015/16)

Comment: @RichHarris Gotcha, removed ithe `include` call. I'm having trouble where rollup is complaining about a ton of deps that it should not need, I updated the repo any ideas? github.com/reggi/example-rollup-failure-async

Comment: @RichHarris this error is similar to what's happening in my real codebase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748665/rollup-issue-resolve-failed-mootools-already-loaded-must-be-run-with-ava